# Artificial Intelligence: Blocksworld heuristic A* solution approach

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I am developing a heuristic solution for Blocksworld problem.

I tried using number of blocks out of place as my h(n). It seems little ineffective.

Can someone please point out a suitable heuristic for the problem and explain with few examples how it will work.

```
Blocksworld Problem Example:

Initial(starting State):
Stack 0: D,B
Stack 1: A,E
Stack 2: C
Stack 3: F


Goal State:
Stack 0: A,B,C,D,E,F
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the "blocksword" problem and couldn't find any good resources related to it. Can you define what the problem requirement is?

Comment: @Cristy:  I have added an example of the problem.

Comment: Maybe you can ask your professor or TA for help instead of random strangers on the Internet who don't know anything about this problem or your background.

Comment: Maybe "Blocksworld" is actually Towers of Hanoi?

Answer (score 0):

The Blocksworld problem consists of stacks of wooden blocks, which are labelled, a table, and a desired end position. It is permitted to remove the top block and place it on another stack or on the table (start a new stack), but not to move a block which is covered by another block. The goal is to get to the end state in the minimum number of moves.

Using A*, we need a heuristic for whether the move is taking is nearer to or further from our goal. So score one for each block in place, then score the piles in the end position from bottom to top, counting the distance of the block to the desired position (so if a block is on top,  that scores -1, if it is in the second position, that scores -2, then just do the same for the next block, so it will give you a bit of an inaccurate measure if two blocks are inverted, but hopefully won't be too bad).

I've no idea how this will perform. It's obviously designed as an open programming problem.